# How to show that a cubic function is continuous, differentiable and has image $(-\infty, \infty)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

Suppose we have $f(x) = x^3 - 3x + 2$. How do I show that $f(x) = 5$ has a solution in a formal way?

I know that $f$ is continuous, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = - \infty$ which implies, by [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) that $f(x) = 5$ has a solution.

But the use of limits that way and saying it continuous directly seems like a notation I haven't seen being used by authors as such.

Comment: That's a pretty standard way to go.

Comment: $f(3) >5$ and $f(0) <5$.

Comment: @Zag Can you tell me how I can show that this function is continuous (using limits or the topological definition of continuity)? I understand how to do it, but that looks messy.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, that's probably how I would expect someone to write. But is it informal to write limits the way I did? I heard that writing infinity directly should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with your argument.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you ^_^

Comment: But what is your question ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @geetha290krm, you can observe that $f(3)>5$ and $f(0)<5$. But notice that you don't have to explicitly find those specific points. Since you know that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, which means that $\forall M\in\mathbb{R}\ \exists k\in\mathbb{R}\ \forall x\geq k:f(x) > M$, you have that $\exists k\in\mathbb{R}\ \forall x\geq k:f(x)>5$ by taking $M=5$. Similarly, since you know $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, you can find $\exists k'\in\mathbb{R}\ \forall x\leq k':f(x)<5$. Hence, since $f(k')<5$ and $f(k)>5$, you know by continuity that $\exists x\in(k',k):f(x)=5$. This is the formal reason why you can indeed apply the IVT on the limiting case (it is actually rigorous).

Answer (score 1):

A constant function and the identity function are continuous. The sum and product of two continuous functions is continuous. (These properties are easy to prove from the first principles.) So any polynomial function is continuous.

As soon as you find two values of the polynomial on either side of $5$, you are done, differentiability is not required.

Comment: @solowsupremacy already knew that $f$ is continuous "I know that $f$ is continuous,$\dots$"

Comment: @DankaMakabre: did you read the title ?

Comment: [Theoretically](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/1122499) , all the information of the question must be contained in the body "After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title." The thing is that, on this question, the title doesn't represent the body of the question.

Comment: @DankaMakabre: the body is in fact asking no specific question.

Comment: It's true that it isn't that clear what the question is. @solowsupremacy wrote "How do I show that $f(x) =5$ has a solution in a formal way?" and "But the use of limits that way and saying it continuous directly seems like a notation I haven't seen being used by authors as such." by which an interpretation could be that the question is "Can the argument with infinities be formalized such that we can indeed apply the IVT?" although it's not the only interpretation possible.

Comment: @DankaMakabre: I asled the OP a clarification. From my experience, such clarifications rarely come, though.

Comment: Yves and @DankaMakabre, my queries were pretty much answered in the comments. But between the both of you, Danka interpreted it correctly. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @solowsupremacy: didn't you say "Can you tell me how I can show that this function is continuous" ??